# How to join two rabbitmq nodes on EC2 -

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, cluster-computing

I have two Ubuntu instances in the EC2 and I want to cluster them.

One ip will be refered as - X (the "net addr" ifconfig displayed IP) and its public ip will be reffered as PX.
the other ip is Y and its public is Y.

So now I did the following on both machines.

1. installed the latest rabbbitmq.
2. installed the management plugin.
3. opened the port for 5672 (rabbit) and 15672(management plugin)
4. connected to rabbit with my test app.
5. connected to the ui.

So now for the cluster.
I did the following commands

on X

```
rabbitmqctl cluster_status
```

got the node name which was 'rabbit@ip-X' (where X is the inner IP)
on Y

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@ip-X
```

I got

```
"The nodes provided are either offline or not running"
```

Obviously this is the private ip, so the other instance cant connect.
How do I tell the second instance where the first is located?

**EDIT**
Firewall is completely off, I have a telnet connection from one remote to the other
(to ports 5672(rmq),15672 (ui), 4369 (cluster port)). 
The cookie on both servers (and the hash of the cookie in the logs is the same).

when recorded tcp when running the join cluster command and watched in wireshark. I saw the following (no ack. )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtcT3.png
[image]

so I closed the firewall using 
       sudo ufw disable
(just for the tests) and I re-typed 
       sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@ip-XX
and the connection was created - but terminated by the remote rabbit
here :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vMn3.png
[image]

and the message is still
"The nodes provided are either offline or not running"

(the remote rabbit app is definitely running)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the nodes can access each other. RabbitMQ uses distributed Erlang primitives for communication across the nodes, so you also have to open up a few ports in the firewall. See:

http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon#firewalls

for details.

You should also use the same data center for your nodes in the cluster, since RabbitMQ can get really sad on network partitions. If your nodes are in different data centers, you should use the shovel or federation plugin instead of clustering for replication of data.

Edit: don't forget to use the same Erlang cookie on all nodes, see http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html for details.

Comment: Thanks. Firewall is completely off, I have a telnet connection from one remote to the other (to ports 5672(rmq),15672 (ui), 4369 (cluster port)), the cookie (and the hash of the cookie in the logs is the same). updating answer.

Comment: Another thing is that the default init script will start erlang with the `-sname` option, so FQDNs or IP addresses can't be used to refer to nodes. Can you put the short hostname of the other node into /etc/hosts on each node and try creating the cluster using the short hostname?

Comment: Is this still relevant if I see in the Wireshark that a connection was created and then terminated?

Comment: The screenshot shows epmd responding - it seems it can't find your node based on your IP. Try the trick with the hosts file as described above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue are probably TCP ports that should be opened.
You should do the following:

1) Create a Security Group for the Rabbit Servers (both will use it)
   we will call it: rabbit-sg

2) In the Security Group, Define the following ports:

```
All TCP            TCP          0 - 65535     sg-xxxx (rabbit-sg)
SSH                TCP             22         0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule    TCP            4369        0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule    TCP            5672        0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule    TCP            15672       0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule    TCP            25672       0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule    TCP            35197       0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule    TCP            55672       0.0.0.0/0
```

3) make sure both EC2 use this security group,
   note that we opened all TCP between the EC2

4) make sure the rabbit cookie is the same and that you reboot the EC2
   after changing it in the slave EC2